# Can Someone explain the database concept difference between mysql an Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I have started working with mysql earlier, where different database meant completely different database, and I can create delete databases.
but when I started to working with oracle, the structure really confused me, the 'database' term means the same in Oracle as Mysql? If not whats the difference?
Thanks!

Comment: [https://db-engines.com/en/system/MySQL%3BOracle] refere this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between MySQL and Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954076/differences-between-mysql-and-oracle-db)

Comment: Another similar question that deals with the concept of "database" in MySQL and Oracle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540982/whats-the-difference-between-oracle-and-mysql-when-interpreting-create-databas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Oracle and Mysql when interpreting "Create Database "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540982/whats-the-difference-between-oracle-and-mysql-when-interpreting-create-databas)

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#i1026408) explain the difference (and migration tips):

> 2.2.5.1 Databases
>   When migrating MySQL databases to Oracle, SQL Developer maps each **MySQL database to a tablespace in Oracle**. Database objects, such as tables, indexes and views are stored in the respective tablespaces and are referenced from the Oracle schema for the user that owns them.

Comment: So in oracle it is actually a single database. and what we mean by database is mysql is considered as tablespaces from different schema?

Comment: MySQL's database equal to Oracle's tablespace